# No more description of tags in Ask page

Tags: bug, tags, bug-reporting-process

In the past, when I was asking a question, entering a tag in the `Tags` box would not only show the autocomplete list, but for each it would show the tag description when moused over.

Now only the list of autocomplete matching list of tags will be shown with no descriptions.

I am using Chrome in Windows.

---

Following @Cody Gray's comments, I turned on CDT, and indeed the response from the Ajax call https://meta.stackoverflow.com/filter/tags?q=lang (where lang are the letters I typed in the Tags box) did return the `Exerpt` in the Json body. So it looks like a bug in the client scripts? CDT console showed no errors though.

For example, `lang` would return:

```
[{"IsDiverged":false,"IsNew":null,"Count":75,"InfoUrl":"/tags/languages/info",
  "Excerpt":"For questions about the use of languages other than English.",
  "Synonyms":"","SynonymOf":null,"Name":"languages"}, 
 {"IsDiverged":false,"IsNew":null,"Count":21,"InfoUrl":"/tags/language-versions/info",
  "Excerpt":"A tag for discussing language-version-related issues, such as answering practices when a desired language version is not mentioned.",
   "Synonyms":"","SynonymOf":null,"Name":"language-versions"},    
  {"IsDiverged":false,"IsNew":null,"Count":5,"InfoUrl":"/tags/code-languages/info",
   "Excerpt":null,"Synonyms":"","SynonymOf":null,"Name":"code-languages"}
]
```

Comment: No repro on Chrome for Windows 10. I still get the tag descriptions in the pop-up box.

Comment: AFAIR, it didn't work like that either. You had to *click the tag first to make it editable*, then it will show the tag excerpt pop-up, and the autocomplete list. I remember I even had to double-click sometimes to make the pop-up appear

Comment: @CodyGray The descriptions are coming in the autocomplete Ajax calls, but not displayed. See my updated question.